# JavaScript - make a custom prompt

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a custom prompt that will return the user input.

Example:

```
    function ask(txt){
    var element = document.createElement("div")
    element.innerHTML = `<p> ` + txt + `</p> <br>`
    var input = document.createElement("input")
    input.type = 'text'
    input.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
if(e.key == 'Enter'){
return this.value;
}
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem/question exactly?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: SO you created elements, you never added it to the DOM.

Comment: I know, I was just giving an example, if I added them, it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

let person = prompt("Please enter your name");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I meant, I want it to be custom.

Comment: Let me get the question right u need to change the text on the prompt dynamically

Comment: No, I mean with custom CSS and maybe icons, etc